# Incompatible types - cannot be converted to java.lang.Class<T>

Tags: java

This code:

```java
  @Override
  public <T extends Comparable, B extends ComparableBinding> void transactPersistentEntityStore(
      String xodusRoot, String dir, boolean isReadOnly,
      StoreTransactionalExecutable txn) {
    Map<Class<T>, B> propertyTypeMap = new HashMap<Class<T>, B>();
    propertyTypeMap.put(EmbeddedArrayIterable.class, EmbeddedEntityBinding.BINDING);
    propertyTypeMap.put(EmbeddedEntityIterable.class, EmbeddedEntityBinding.BINDING);
    DatabaseManagerImpl.getInstance()
        .transactPersistentEntityStore(xodusRoot + dir, isReadOnly, propertyTypeMap, txn);
  }
```

Throws a compiler error:

```
Error:(82,46) java: incompatible types: java.lang.Class<com.backend.model.EmbeddedArrayIterable> cannot be converted to java.lang.Class<T>
```

Even when **EmbeddedArrayIterable** is

```java
public class EmbeddedArrayIterable implements Serializable, ByteIterable {
}
public interface ByteIterable extends Comparable<ByteIterable> {
}
```

What could be missing here?

Update:
Showing code for **transactPersistentEntityStore** method

```java
  @Override
  public <T extends Comparable, B extends ComparableBinding> void transactPersistentEntityStore(
      String dir, boolean isReadOnly, Map<Class<T>, B> customPropertyTypes,
      StoreTransactionalExecutable txn) {
    final PersistentEntityStore entityStore =
        getPersistentEntityStore(dir, isReadOnly, customPropertyTypes);
    entityStore.executeInTransaction(txn);
  }
```

Comment: Can you show what types of parameters `transactPersistentEntityStore` needs? It certainly doesn't need a `Map<Class<T>, B>`, does it?

Comment: Since I see at least one raw type in your code: [What is a raw type and why shouldn't we use it?](//stackoverflow.com/q/2770321)

Comment: @Sweeper the method uses `Map<Class<T>, B> customPropertyTypes` as I have shown in the updated post

Comment: Your question has two implementations of `transactPersistentEntityStore`. And which line is 82, where the error occurs?

Comment: @tgdavies the first one in the chain

Comment: Which line is 82, where the error occurs? You need to give an example we can compile which produce the error.